# Finding the limit of a multivariable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm working through a piece of homework for my class and I now realize that my prof didn't exactly explain well how to prove that a limit for a multivariable function exists. The question that made me realize this is the following: $$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{y^3x+x^4}{x^3+y^3} $$ From preliminary analysis, I was able to glean that if the limit exists, it equals 0. I plugged the equation into WolframAlpha and confirmed that it does in fact equal 0. I just don't know how to prove this on paper. We didn't learn anything regarding $\epsilon-\delta $ solutions, so that shouldn't be the way I'd have to show it.

Answer (score 1):

In fact we can write the fraction $\frac{y^3x + x^4}{x^3 + y^3}$ as $\frac{x(x^3 + y^3)}{x^3 + y^3}$ which then equals $x$. Taking the limit at $(x_0,y_0) =(0,0)$, we have the answer as $0$.

Comment: Thanks so much. Thats so simple. I should have gotten that haha

Comment: Well, the function isn't defined at all on a line through $\;(0,0)\;$ , namely $\;y=-x\;$ , and then some would say the limit of the function cannot exist when $\;(x,y)\to(0,0)\;$ because we cannot evaluate the function at all in **any** complete neighborhood of $\;(0,0)\;$ ... I think I'd be one of those "some", but I haven't really given a deep thought to this matter.